# How can I implement SOTag textbox in asp.net website?

Tags: c#, javascript, php, asp.net

I am trying to use SOTag textbox in a asp.net website(Here [link](https://github.com/iog3/SOTag) of SOTag textbox).

The php example is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SOTag</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
padding:30px;
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
}
pre {
border:#ccc 1px solid;
background:#EFEFEF;
padding:10px;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/so_tag.css?<?php echo rand(0,1000); ?>">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/so_tag.js?<?php echo rand(0,1000); ?>"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>jQuery.SO_Tag</h2>
<p>First a little description about what this plugin is for. This plugin is designed to be used with a backend database full of tags, not to be able to tag whatever you or the user wants to. I may add that feature if people want to but you cannot currently let your users add custom tags using this plugin</p>
<p>It's easy to get started, first include the JavaScript files and the CSS</p>
<pre>
<?php echo htmlentities('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/so_tag.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/so_tag.js"></script>'); ?>
</pre>
<br />
<pre>
<?php echo htmlentities('<form action="result.php" method="post">
<input type="text" value="3_php" name="single_example" id="single_example" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(\'#single_example\').sotag({
description : true
});
</script>'); ?>
</pre>
<br />
<p><strong>Here is an example with multiple tag fields</strong></p>
<form action="result.php" method="post">
<p>Programming words (example: PHP)</p>
<input type="text" value="" name="multi_example_programming_tags" class="multi_example_programming_tags" />
<br />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.multi_example_programming_tags').sotag({
description : true
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My aspx page is this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
       <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="js/so_tag.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/so_tag.css" />
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
       <title>Example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
           <input type="text" value="" name="multi_example_programming_tags" class="multi_example_programming_tags" />
       <br />
       </form>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $('.multi_example_programming_tags').sotag({
              description: true
       });
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Then I've changed in `js/so_tag.js`

```
autocomplete_URL: 'SOTag.php'
```

with

```
autocomplete_URL: 'MyPage.cs'
```

Now I don't understand how to implement result.php and SOtag.php in c#. Someone could help me?

**EDIT1**

I have done what you have explained but it dosen't work.

In web.config I wrote

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
    <add url="~/Index.aspx" mappedUrl="~/SoTag.ashx" /> 
  </urlMappings>
```

But in the index.aspx the result is the json string.

I have upload the project example on MEGA--> here you can find the [link](https://mega.co.nz/#!q0B0SRCZ!yMI_L8G0PUNzd_uUw3MhgdySQoNV87KjkOZOW6Rj8Gc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work on asp.net you need to follow some steps.

1. Make the autocomplete handler.
2. Change the `so_tag.js` to ask the new handler.
3. Attach it to any asp.net page.

### The handler

How you make it. You create a handler `SoTag.ashx`, and there you return on jSon format the tags. Here is just a simple return to see the return format.

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    // Simple one TAG format SO_Tag, and one more for test
    string cRet = @"
    [{
        ""id"": 10, 
        ""tag"": ""SO_Tag"",
        ""tag_description"": ""SO_Tag: Tagging system based on StackOverflows tag search""
    },{
        ""id"": 11, 
        ""tag"": ""asp.net"",
        ""tag_description"": ""ASP.NET is a web application framework developed by Microsoft to allow programmers to build dynamic web sites and web applications.""
    }]";

    context.Response.Write(cRet);   
}
```

On your code, on this file you must open your database, get the `q` query string, ask your database for the

- ID
- tag
- tag_description

return them on json format, and the plugin shows them.

### Change the so_tag.js

On the so_tag, find the autocomplete_URL, and change to the asp.net handler, as:

`autocomplete_URL: 'SoTag.ashx',`

### The asp.net page

And the most simple, just attach it to any input control.

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="so_tag.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="so_tag.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() 
    {
        jQuery('#<%=txtSoTags.ClientID%>').sotag({
            description : true
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSoTags" Width="300">1_some, 2_example, 3_tags</asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Finally

The only difficulty here is to complete the handler to read data, from your database, that you need to add a lot of informations of the tags, and return them back with json format.

This code here is tested and work, and here is the screenshot:

[image]
<sub>(source: [planethost.gr](http://www.planethost.gr/so/SoTags.gif))</sub>

### Small Improvements

The `SO_tag.js` is make too many calls on every key press, is better to give some time to finish the typing, so add use/change this code on the `keyup` bind.

```
    var cKeyPressTimer = null;
    // Now if the user starts typing show results
    elem.bind('keyup', function(e) 
    {
        if(cKeyPressTimer)
            clearTimeout(cKeyPressTimer);
        cKeyPressTimer = setTimeout(SO_update_results, 500);
    });
```

Comment: I've done what you have written but I have some problems. I have edited the question. @Aristos

Comment: @Tinwor I see your code, just remove the map from web.config. Then open your browser debug tools to see if can not find any of the files. Normally all the rest are correct and must work (with out the map). To see it work, you see the page, start typing inside, and then open the drop down... make sure that the javascript files are found, open your debug tools to double check it

Comment: It's possible add a filter for the choices? Something like the filter in the tag's textbox of stackoverflow. For example if I write PHP it shows only the tags that contains php and not, for example, asp.net
@Aristos

Comment: @Tinwor Yes is possible, the plugin is send the `q` url parametre, capture that and filter your results.

Comment: @Aristos, I will update the SOTag source code with your improvement :) - iog3